# Is there a Mat arithmetic + operator alternative for UMat?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'am trying to applying homomorphic filter to my video player program.

While I was writing code using UMat, I found something incompatible with the code using the existing Mat.

in Mat code

```
cv::Mat temp;
someImage.convertTo(temp,CV_32FC1)
temp = temp + 0.01
```

temp = temp + 0.01 
What does this mean?
And how can I using this option in UMat ?

Comment: `temp = temp + 0.01` is a per element addition, i.e. every pixel of temp will be added 0.01

Comment: thank you! Does UMat provide that funtion?

Comment: [cv::add](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add)

Comment: Sorry, but I read that as homophobic filter. It got my attention, but unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV's `operator+(const Mat& a, const Scalar& s)` adds a scalar value to each element of the matrix. It's practically the same as calling [`void add(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst, InputArray mask=noArray(), int dtype=-1)`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add).

`InputArray` interface accepts `Mat`s and `UMat`s as well as `Scalar`s, so you can just call

```
cv::UMat temp(3, 3, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));
cv::add(temp, 0.01, temp);
```